# How to group elements by type in a JFace TreeViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, treeviewer

I am writing a treeviewer which displays my model, which includes three classes **Project**, **Course** and **Student**. Each project can have multiple courses and each course can have multiple students.

I am using the TreeViewer class of JFace.

To Display this model, I have created a treeviewer, which looks like the following.

[image]

I want these Courses (course1, 2 and 3) to be grouped under a node **COURSES** like following.

[image]

Is there a function to group elements under a parent by the element type?
Or can I introduce this dummy node "Courses", which is actually not a part of my model.

Comment: This is all just a matter of how your content provider is implemented for your model. It can tell the viewer whatever you want, as long as it fulfills the interface.

Comment: I already know this. I would like to know how to add a node "Courses" between the nodes "Project" and its children, without modifying the model ? What changes to make to the content provider?

Comment: The content provider is responsible for the displayed structure of the tree. So you must make the provider return some sort of 'courses' object as a child of the project with the individual courses as children of the 'courses' object.

Comment: As you first thought, you'd introduce a dummy node that exists only for the representation in the tree.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. I could introduce a dummy node by following your advice.